# Porting from ASP.NET 5 to Dotnet Core 2 : Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.IApplicationBuilder.UseWebSockets() replacement

Tags: asp.net, .net-core-2.0

We have an existing ASP.NET 5 application that is being ported to dotnet core 2.
The current code uses the method `IApplicationBuilder.UseWebSockets()` from `Microsoft.AspNet.Builder` but in dotnet core 2 the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder` does not contain this method.

I checked the [migration document provided by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/) as well as the documentation for the new [Use()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.iapplicationbuilder.use?view=aspnetcore-2.0) method it provides but it wasn't clear how `UseWebSockets()` must be replaced.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by adding

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets;
```

The documentation is available at on the [microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets)

The package is available at [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets/)